# change parameters value of a puppet module in a inherited node

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I wrote a module which sets the mail of root in /etc/alias using the command "alias"
I have a master node where I set this email like

```
node master {
    class{"rootmail": mail_dst => "xxxx@domain.com"}
}
```

All child nodes inherit of the master as advised on many books.
I have some particular child that need another email for root but the have to inherit from the master node. I tried to invoke the class rootmail but it causes error and says that the module were already declared.

Does one of you have had this case once ? Is there a turn around?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#extlookup

extlookup is your answer. This function allows to use common value (xxx), and redeclare it only where it's really necessary.

Comment: Hiera should be used over extlookup these days where possible.

Comment: Sounds nice, but is there another way? I'd like to avoid to have an external definition file. Thanks